# how to create a new table with the same schema as an existing table in dolphindb?

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

how to create a new table with the same schema as an existing table in dolphindb?

I have established a table in dolphindb, and now I want to establish another empty table with the same schema. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The field definition of the original table can be obtained through “schema().colDefs”:

```py
pt = loadTable("dfs://GPS_data", "pt")
shema =  pt.schema().colDefs
col1 = exec name from shema
col2 = exec typeString from shema
t = table(10:0, col1, col2)
```

Or obtain it through an invalid where condition:

```py
t=select * from pt where Send_time=1970.01.01T00:00:00.000
```